# Blazor clilent app urls return 404 on IIS

Tags: iis, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a strange issue occurring when I deploy my Blazor client web assembly app to my local IIS server.

The deployment works and I can access the web app via a localhost url I have configured for the web app.  I can navigate between pages using the links in my app.  However when I refresh the page, or paste the exact same url into the browser directly IIS returns a 404 not found error.

For example, the url for the app is https://localhost/ which will load the main page and the side menu.
The side menu contains links such as /login
clicking the link updates the address bar to https://localhost/login and the route is loaded successfully.
Now if I refresh the page, or copy and paste the url into a new browser tab, I get the IIS 404 error page.

I already have the base href='/' in the head of the index.html file.

When I run my app in debug in Visual Studio, it all works fine.

I'm not sure what else to try.

Comment: You missed the necessary URL rewrite rules when deploying to IIS. It worked on VS because VS generated the correct rules in IIS Express applicationHost.config file.

Comment: @Lex Li Where I can find these rules, I couldn't find anything in the officlal Blazor docs

Comment: Then I wonder what is the "official Blazor docs" you are reading. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly?view=aspnetcore-7.0#rewrite-urls-for-correct-routing "When deploying to an IIS server, you can use the URL Rewrite Module with the app's published web.config file. For more information, see the IIS section."

Comment: @Lex Li yes, but no example of what the actual url rewrite should be which is what I was looking for